# How to tell what version of PCI Express slot your system has?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

I have just bought Lenovo H50 90C1 desktop system.  It has one PCI Express slot, unmarked (does not say 3.0).  There is no name on the motherboard other than Lenovo, it is an internal cheap motherboard without any specs.  Neither the manual nor the website, nor the sales know anything about which PCI Express version this slot is, 2.0 or 3.0.  Device Manager also does not say what version.

I have to know, whether this thing is PCI Express 2.0 or 3.0.

Comment: I looked up the model and the processor on the C models is a [J2900](http://ark.intel.com/products/78868/Intel-Pentium-Processor-J2900-2M-Cache-up-to-2_67-GHz) - its bay trail based and supports a single pcie 2.0/x4 connector. I'm rather doubtful if this is the case, that you want to put a *good* gpu there.

Answer (score 11):

[HWiNFO](http://www.fosshub.com/HWiNFO.html) has more reliable detection than CPUID.

For example, on my system CPUID wasn't able to detect PCI-E revision, but HWINFO was.

[image]

Comment: I tried this and I am pretty sure that your screenshot is showing the PCIe version of the device plugged into the slot rather then the capability of the slot itself.

Comment: @Clifford Hmm, ok. I wonder if anyone has come up with a reliable way to pin this down.

Comment: @Clifford the screenshot was made on a laptop with chipset integrated GPU with no other devices, so the value showed is the maximum value ever possible on this chipset, so technically value is the same as the slot value, I am very doubtful about some 3rd party device having higher speed than the native GPU

Comment: This is the right answer. It does say `PCI Express Version Supported: v2.4` with v6.42

Answer (score 1):

CPUID is a pretty good tool that tells you a lot about your CPU/Motherboard/RAM. http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

You can run it without installing with the ZIP version.

[image: CPU-Z Mainboard screenshot]

Comment: Didn't see this comment for years, but CPU-Z has the PCIe version in the "Motherboard" tab as "Bus Specs". https://i.imgur.com/wPBZb33.png

Comment: Oh snap! My bad! I don't know how I missed that. I was wrong :/ If you add that screenshot to the answer with annotations, I can revoke my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

When I was young, I used a software called "everest" to check the hardwares and most of the time, it could tell me tons of information. Seems it is available through the cnet. If you really can't figure out, treat it as 2.0 may be a good choice.

Comment: Great.  I found this software on CNET, I tried to downloaded, it started downloading strange other things I did not need, and my PC said there is a Trojan in there and it was quarantined.

Comment: I almost downloaded it when I saw "Great, found on CNET"...maybe "Avoid" should be the first word.